# Help for Linear algebra done right 5B exercise 9

Tags: linear-algebra

9. Suppose V is finite-dimensional, Let T be an operator on V, and let $v \in V and v \neq 0$. Let p be a nonzero polynomial of smallest degree such that $p(T)v = 0$. Prove that every zero of p is an eigenvalue of T

I am confused over this question since it seems to imply that every nonzero vector of V  is an eigenvector.

My pf of question: let $\lambda$ Be zero of p, then $p(T)v$ = $(T-\lambda)(v)q(T)(v)$, then clearly $\lambda$ must be an eigenvalue otherwise $q(T)(v)=0$ while being of lower degree than $p$ thus contradicting the hypothesis.

However the proof above would also imply that $v$ is an eigenvector. Since $v$ was chosen arbitrarily, I would conclude that every element of V is an eigenvector which doesn’t seem to be correct.

And also, if question were to choose $v$ such that it was always an eigenvector. Then, clearly the polynomial $p$ would always just be $T-\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is just the corresponding eigenvalue of $v$, making the question redundant.

I am not very good at phrasing so if anything i say is confusing, let me know and i will my best to clarify

Here is my attempt at making it as detailed as possible: let $deg(p)=n$ and $\lambda$ be zero of $p$, then by the division algorithm $p(z)=(z-\lambda)q(z)$ where $q$ is another polynomial st $deg(q)=n-1$. Then we have that $p(T)v=((T-\lambda)(q(T))(v)$, we can further simplify this into $p(T)v=(Tv-\lambda v)(q(T)(v))$. Then. since $p$ was chosen such that $p(T)v=0$, we have that $0=(Tv-\lambda v)(q(T)(v))$. FSOC, If we assume $q(T)v=0$, then $p$ is no longer the polynomial of smallest degree. Thus $(T-\lambda)(v)=0$ and doing a bit of algebra we get that $Tv=\lambda v$ and thus $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T, completing the proof.

Resolved: I figured out the problem with my reasonining, it boils down to the fact that any $(p(T)q(T))v=p(T)(q(Tv))$ whereas I treated $(p(T)q(T))v=(p(T)(v))(q(T)(v))$ which is completely wrong since that's now how linear map multiplicationn is defined a tall.

Also:oops forget to add the identity map at the back of every lambda

Comment: The question assumes that $p$ exists but that might not be the case

Comment: Ah okay that makes a lot of sense. But if p were to exist, then v must be an eigenvector, would p being of smallest degree always be of the form ($z-\lambda$)

Comment: You haven't explained very well how your equation $p(T)v=(T-\lambda)v\, q(T)(v)= 0$ proves that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. One problem is that this equation is malformed: what is the product of the vectors $(T-\lambda)v$ and $q(T)v$? If you fixed this equation and carefully wrote out why $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then I think your difficulty would clear up.

Comment: I have added a more detailed proof to the bottom of the original post and hopefully rectified the equation so that it is correct now. I am still expericing the same difficulty of why p wouldnt have degree 1 and always be of the form $z-\lambda$ if v is an eigenvector

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe thanks alot for the reply, took me quite awhile but I managed to figure it out now. I wasnt treating the product of linear maps properly which led to the malformed equation as you have pointed out

Comment: Please note that $T-\lambda$ makes no sense.

Comment: @Koro oh yeah, your right, still relatively new to the topic, forgot to add the identity I behind every lambda

Comment: Glad you figured it out.